# WiFi ONLY works when booting "fast startup" in Windows 10 and not working in Ubuntu at all

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wireless-networking, bios, multi-boot

This is the first time I write to this forum, because it's also the first time I couldn't find any answer with search-function, so please be indulgent.

Some time ago I replaced my Wifi-PCI-Module in my HP Pavilion G6 2346sg Laptop, to profit from 5GHz Wifi and Bluetooth function.
As the BIOS has a WiFi-Module-Whitelist and has RSA-Signature, not allowing any newer Module to be installed, after hours of research I found a workaround , which involved tapeing two PCI-pins (see http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/broadcom-bcm4352-bcm94352hmb.755647/page-2#post-9808817). It seemed that everything worked.

Now to the bigger Problem:

After couple of days I noticed, that the WiFi-Module stopped working after restarting Windows 10. Literally ONLY after reboot. The WiFi module was recognized, but it was impossible to put it ON. I could get it working again only by shutting down Windows and starting it again. I could live with that behaviour without really being affected by that.

But today I installed Ubuntu as Dual-Boot.
There the problems started:
First of all I cannot get WiFi working in Ubuntu. It recognizes the PCI-Module after installing the correct driver, but it's not possible to put it to ON in the System-Config. Just the same behaviour as on Windows, when restarted.
Secondly, I had to deactivate "fast startup" in Windows for dual-boot, which rendered the WiFi-Module to not being activated at all in Windows, just like on restart.
So somehow the "fast startup"-function *activates* the WiFi.

Is there any solution for these two problems? Or is the Signed-BIOS the problem there?

Thank you!

Timethy96

EDIT: The used WiFi-module is BCM4352HMB.

Comment: try install driver on bcm4352 in ubuntu (out of the box does not work) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found/416269#416269

Comment: Lol this isn't a good idea... The solution to this is 1. Buy a adapter that's in the whitelist. 2. Modify your bios with an image that has the whitelist removed. While I don't like that Lenovo or hp does this. This is not the approach to having a stable computer

Answer (score 0):

1. try install driver on bcm4352 in ubuntu (out of the box does not work)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416180/ubuntu-no-wifi-adapter-found/416269#416269

2. the most correct is to fix the BIOS so that all the cards get into the whitelist (remove whitelist)

https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/this-is-no-request-thread-hp-compaq-bioses-how-to-modify-the-bios.7681/page-15#post-111460

Forum: [www.bios-mods.com/forum](http://www.bios-mods.com/forum)

The profile of the moder who lobbies the fashion for hp whitelist remove:

[www.bios-mods.com/forum/User-camiloml](http://www.bios-mods.com/forum/User-camiloml)

Well, the actual link to the archive of his works, which can be found in his signature:

[www.bios-mods.com/BIOS/](http://www.bios-mods.com/BIOS/)

how to do it - translate and read (sorry, that in Russian):

https://geektimes.ru/post/256608/

https://geektimes.ru/post/256732/